# Get existing Solution name before Project template creation in C++ custom Wizard

Tags: javascript, c++, visual-c++

I have created a new project template using C++ custom Wizard(VS 2010).I want to make some customizations while adding my new project template in OnFinish event of Default.js file.

My project requirement needs the existing solution name appeneded with "Resources" text as the name of my new project added using my C++ wizard.

eg. Solution Name : MySolution
    Existing Project name : MyWin32Project
    New Project name should be created as : MySolutionResources

So to acheive this, i need the solution name of existing solution before adding my project.Currently i am appending the "Resources" string to the project name given while creation of template.I used the line below:

```
var strProjectName = wizard.FindSymbol('PROJECT_NAME');
var strNewProjectName = strProjectName + "Resources";
selProj = CreateCustomProject(strNewProjectName, strNewProjectPath);
```

I have tried with following line but its giving me the project name given while creation:

```
var strSolutionName = wizard.FindSymbol("VS_SOLUTION_NAME");//not giving me the solution name
var strNewProjectName = strSolutionName + "Resources";
```

Can someone help me on this please??

Regards,
Deepthi

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution..!!

Write the below code to get the name of an existing solution:

```
var strSolutionPath = dte.Solution.Properties.Item("Path").Value;
var strFullSolutionName = strSolutionPath.substr(strSolutionPath.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
var strSolutionName = strFullSolutionName.substr(0, strFullSolutionName.lastIndexOf(".sln"));
```

Regards,
Deepthi

Comment: I think it's a bug they fixed only in VS 2017. Now VS 2017 suddenly started creating .sln and .vcxproj in different directories as it turns out it always had to do considering function CreateProject in common.js.